# Usage of rosavent in "climatol" package

Tags: r

I have a problem using the "climatol" package.
In the package example:

```
  data("windfr")
  rosavent(windfr, 4, 4, ang=-3*pi/16, main="Annual windrose")
```

produces the following graph:
[Sample graph http://gallery.r-enthusiasts.com/graphiques/graph_123.png](http://gallery.r-enthusiasts.com/graphiques/graph_123.png)

The "windfr" table has no mention of the wind speed classes used in the legend.
The table his made of 4 rows (the four classes) but no mention of the classes limits.
Where does it come from in the legend?
Thanks for your help.
All the best,
Vincent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The labels in your legend are just the rownames of your data. Try

```
data("windfr")
rownames(windfr)
rownames(windfr)[1] <- "HUHU"
rosavent(windfr, 4, 4, ang=-3*pi/16, main="Annual windrose")
```